# Which tense would you use in this case?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

In French, I've seen that when translating something like "In March, I went to his house" you would use the present tense instead of the past tense, "En mars, je vais chez lui", at least I think so. Or when translating "Ever since I was young, I played the piano" you'd say "Depuis que je suis jeune, je joue du piano". But when saying something like "Back then, I thought that he was an idiot" would you say

> Ce temps là, je pensais qu'il était un idiot

Or

> Ce temps là, je pensais qu'il est un idiot

Comment: "In March, I went to his house" != "En mars, je vais chez lui"  |
  
En mars, je vais chez lui → I’m going to his house in march  |
  
In March, I went to his house → J’ai été chez lui en mars/au mois de mars

Comment: That's strange, I don't understand why but I think I've seen people use the present tense when referring to something they did on a week day like "Je mange le mercredi"

Comment: "Je mange le mercredi" = "I eat on wednesdays"

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.

Comment: "Je mange le mercredi" is "I do eat on wednesday" or "I use to eat on wednesday". If you mean "I ate on wednesday" it's "J’ai mangé mercredi" (or the simple past : "je mangeai mercredi")

Comment: @Stéphane 'Je suis allé' et non 'j'ai été'.

Comment: @Stephane "In March, I went to his house" = "En mars, je vais chez lui", if you use _Present de narration_ (present tense used to relate past events), which is, I think, what Marco asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> En ce temps là, je pensais que c’était/qu’il était un idiot.

Comment: « À cette époque » peut être utilisé comme alternative à « En ce temps là ». C'est probablement l'expression la plus usitée des deux dans le langage courant.

Comment: « ... que c'était un idiot. » ou «... qu'il était idiot » (pas d'article indéfini dans le deuxième cas).

Answer (score 1):

The right translation of "Back then, I thought that he was an idiot" is

> En ce temps là/ à cette époque là, je pensais que c’était un idiot

You can't say *Je pensais que **c'est** un idiot*, because you alreay used the verb *penser* in the past time (Imparfait)

If you wanted to use the present, you should have said

> A cette époque là, je pense que c'est un idiot

The same thing for the sentence "En Mars, je vais chez lui". It's the present tense, but you know that is something happening in the past (in March)

But why the present is used for past events, you could ask ?

Well, it's what we call in french ***Le présent de narration***, and it is used to relate past events with a more vivid appearance, like if they were happening now. It is, for example, frenquently used in novels :

> Ce matin-là, j'arrive en retard.

This *présent de narration* has the same value of a past tense.

Comment: "En Mars, je vais chez lui" without further context (and there is none in OP's question), shows a future event, not a past event.

Comment: @Laure without context It may show a futur or a past event, but in the question the sentence is given as the translation of "In March, I went to his house", so, past !

Comment: But OP's translation or their understanding of the French sentence is wrong. And there's nothing shows it is the "présent de narration". To make such a statement you need a lot more context. No good answer can be given if OP does not clarify his question.

Comment: You should ask him then, make the comment on OP's question !

Comment: Stéphane's comments already point this out...

Comment: Stephane commented that _"In March, I went to his house" != "En mars, je vais chez lui"_ , which is false, because it's possible with _Present de narration_

Comment: I think you're misreading the exclamation mark (pointing to sth wrong) in your quote. What I read is "En mars, je vais chez lui → I’m going to his house in march | In March, I went to his house → J’ai été chez lui en mars/au mois de mars ".

Comment: Ok, I'll try to be clear : "En mars, je vais chez lui "can express **either** futur : "In March, I'm going to his house" **or** past (if it's used as _present de narration_) :"In March, I went to his house". Regardless of the past form "En mars, J'ai été chez lui". Are we okay on that ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> En ce temps là, je pensais qu’il était un idiot.

It's the translation of "back then, ...." Because now you think that he's not. If you think he's actually an idiot you say

> Depuis ce temps là je sais qu'il est un idiot.

And I think in informal french you can use the second sentence in the two cases.

Comment: When someone says or write *je pensais qu'il était un idiot*, I know for sure (s)he is not a native French speaker.